# KVM Guest networking - only one adapter connects to Internet through host's bridge?

Tags: linux, networking, kvm-virtualization

I am attempting to add three interfaces to a KVM guest (required by my hosting provider) and having little luck! I can get only one at a time to work on the guest. If I enable an adapter inside `nmtui` while disabling others on the CentOS 7 guest it will work but other adapters will no longer even ping. I believe there is a problem with my understanding on how bridging works and would like some pointers.

Goal: Setup a bridge on Host and three interfaces on Guest (server provider assigns MAC addresses for me to use)

Info:

```
xxx.yyy.107.27 - assume main IP address of the Host machine
xxx.yyy.107.1 - gateway for the above
255.255.255.192 - netmask for the above
xxx.yyy.168.170 - IP address #1 for Guest
xxx.yyy.168.171 - IP address #2 for Guest
xxx.yyy.168.174 - IP address #3 for Guest
xxx.yyy.168.169 - Gateway for IPs 1-3 given by Provider
255.255.255.248 - Netmask for IPs 1-3 given by Provider
00:50:56:00:a4:33 - MAC for IP 1
00:50:56:00:9a:97 - MAC for IP 2
00:50:56:00:ad:04 - MAC for IP 3
```

Debian 8 host /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# Loopback device:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 2a01:4f8:171:101a::2
  netmask 64
  gateway fe80::1

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
 address xxx.yyy.107.27
 netmask 255.255.255.192
 gateway xxx.yyy.107.1
 broadcast xxx.yyy.107.63
 bridge_ports eth0
 bridge_fd 0
 bridge_stp off
 bridge_waitport 0
 bridge_hello 2
 bridge_maxage 12
```

The Libvirt network:

```
<network>
  <name>Host</name>
  <forward mode='bridge'/>
  <bridge name='br0'/>
</network>
```

The XML configuration of Guest concerning the interfaces:

```
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='00:50:56:00:a4:33'/>
      <source network='Host'/>
      <model type='rtl8139'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='00:50:56:00:9a:97'/>
      <source network='Host'/>
      <model type='rtl8139'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='00:50:56:00:ad:04'/>
      <source network='Host'/>
      <model type='rtl8139'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

CentOS 7 Guest /etc/sysconfig/network-interfaces/ifcfg-eth0-1:

```
HWADDR=00:50:56:00:A4:33
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=eth0
UUID=18f3808e-335a-4932-93e4-683b987ddc07
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
PREFIX=32
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
```

CentOS 7 Guest /etc/sysconfig/network-interfaces/ifcfg-eth1:

```
HWADDR=00:50:56:00:9A:97
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DNS1=213.133.98.98
DNS2=213.133.99.99
DNS3=213.133.100.100
DEFROUTE=no
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=no
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=eth1
UUID=a2c6c1e3-bfb2-4401-99e0-40f723d6d713
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
```

I don't see any file for the third interface, something to do with Network Manager?

Guest's /etc/sysconfig/network:

```
GATEWAY=xxx.yyy.107.1
```

route -n output on Guest:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         xxx.yyy.168.169 0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens8
0.0.0.0         xxx.yyy.168.169 0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth0
xxx.yyy.168.168 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     100    0        0 ens8
xxx.yyy.168.169 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
xxx.yyy.168.170 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
188.40.24.199   xxx.yyy.168.169 255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 ens8
```

route -n output on Host:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         xxx.yyy.107.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
xxx.yyy.107.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 br0
```

It looks like my bridge only allows one of these interfaces to reach the outside world at any given time. I would like to fix this but I'm not sure if I have the setup & understanding correct. I've probably set it up horribly wrong and weird things are happening so appreciate any help.

EDIT 1:
Current state of things on guest's ifconfig:

```
ens8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xxx.yyy.168.174  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast xxx.yyy.168.175
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe00:ad04  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:00:ad:04  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6456  bytes 3735538 (3.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4987  bytes 548563 (535.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xxx.yyy.168.170  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast xxx.yyy.168.170
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe00:a433  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:00:a4:33  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1012  bytes 75375 (73.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 47  bytes 5110 (4.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xxx.yyy.168.171  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast xxx.yyy.168.175
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe00:9a97  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:00:9a:97  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1048  bytes 77065 (75.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 22  bytes 2808 (2.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 12243  bytes 1881497 (1.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12243  bytes 1881497 (1.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Right now only xxx.yyy.168.170 is accessible from outside the guest. The rest is not even on Host.

Host's ifconfig:

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:32:e4:71:a2:87
          inet addr:xxx.yyy.107.27  Bcast:xxx.yyy.107.63  Mask:255.255.255.192
          inet6 addr: fe80::fa32:e4ff:fe71:a287/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20661927 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14207667 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:3370784779 (3.1 GiB)  TX bytes:2529369626 (2.3 GiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:32:e4:71:a2:87
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22402779 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15423843 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:4010564000 (3.7 GiB)  TX bytes:2731403072 (2.5 GiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:21145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2619801 (2.4 MiB)  TX bytes:2619801 (2.4 MiB)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:50:56:00:a4:33
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc50:56ff:fe00:a433/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2028 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7634 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:1219855 (1.1 MiB)  TX bytes:692099 (675.8 KiB)

vnet1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:50:56:00:9a:97
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc50:56ff:fe00:9a97/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6348 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:5154 (5.0 KiB)  TX bytes:520891 (508.6 KiB)

vnet2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:50:56:00:ad:04
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc50:56ff:fe00:ad04/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5080 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12829 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:560230 (547.0 KiB)  TX bytes:4342111 (4.1 MiB)
```

Comment: Who is the service provider? And, why aren't there any IP addresses configured in your guests?

Comment: I have added ifconfig output showing correct IPs assigned by DHCP, the provider is Hetzner.de - they require virtual machines to connect to the network with MAC addresses they provide for IP addresses.

Comment: Your masking of IP addresses is a bit inconsistent in the question. I would prefer that one masks only the first two octets consistently, something like: xxx.yyy.101.23, so that the last two octets match the actual configuration used. Also your broadcast addresses are inconsistent in the VM guest configurations.

Comment: Thank you. I've edited the addresses in hopefully all places to match this preference as it improves readability.

Comment: Thanks. How many interfaces do you have on the host? What is the ifconfig of those?

Comment: The entire /etc/network/interfaces is posted above, I added host's ifconfig to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hetzner has (un)fortunately told me that due to their filtering only one IP address can be active in a virtual machine at a time (?). If you ever order Additional IP addresses from Hetzner for VM purposes, only one will work at any given time per VM. To have multiple IPs on a VM Hetzner provides Subnets (smallest /29 at the moment). I hope this helps anyone that would have a similar problem as this is not outlined in their documentation.

EDIT: This is "resolved" - I will need to wait a few hours before I can accept my answer.